# Firebase iOS query data with partially matching value

Tags: ios, swift, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase `queryEqualToValue` returns items **EQUAL** to the specified key or value. How can we query for items **PARTIALLY MATCH** to the specified key or value?

[Firebase iOS retrieve data documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data)

Comment: As iOSGeek's answer shows, you can do "starts with" type queries with Firebase. But broader `LIKE` searches are not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase

Comment: @frankvanpuffelen Yes, I want to do a LIKE search, I've read the blog post, but the blog post is in 2014, so today, there is still no existing firebase method or feature I can use to accomplish LIKE search?

Comment: There are no LIKE searches directly in Firebase. However, if you structure your data correctly, you can perform [Wildcard Searches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365157/wildcard-query-on-firebase/36366619#36366619). Which is similar.

Comment: Oh, and the answer to this question is also applicable for LIKE type searches. [Real Time Searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870425/swift-how-can-i-use-shouldchangetextinrange-with-firebase-for-real-time-sear/36872475#36872475)

Answer (score 3):

> We can combine startAt() and endAt() to limit both ends of our query.
>   The following example finds all dinosaurs whose name starts with the
>   letter "b":

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs")
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryStartingAtValue("b").queryEndingAtValue("b\u{f8ff}")
   .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

    println(snapshot.key)
})
```

> The f8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point
>   in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in
>   Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a b.

[Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html)

Comment: May I know what does "\u{f8ff}" represents?

Comment: @Alex answer edited with more information about `f8ff` character

Comment: That's . Source - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f8ff/index.htm