# firebase queries and swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a string for eg: "My name is John" stored in Firebase.

How would I query firebase so I can find all the posts in Firebase that have "John" ?

I can search for the first term in a string now using:

```
DataService.dataService.BASE_REF.child("Posts").child(selectedComment.commentKey).queryOrderedByChild("userComment").queryStartingAtValue(comment).queryEndingAtValue(comment+"\u{F8FF}").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
```

where comment = "My"

I read about using Elastic search with Firebase but wanted to check if there was an easier way in Firebase before I looked at ElasticSearch/Flashlight for Firebase,

Comment: You could download all the posts and perform the search on Swift. Not the most elegant solution. . Anyway, Here on Firebase Documentation you can see search examples: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: While an answer has been accepted, the issue is reliance on yet another library to do a substring (wildcard) search. You can do this yourself - it's not easier - but you control the code. See my answer the this question [Wilcard query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365157/wildcard-query-on-firebase/36366619#36366619). In your case, if you are searching for whole words, create a parser that automatically parses the sentence and stores each word. Then substring searches are super quick. It's not a lot of code and disk space is cheap so it's another option.

Comment: The DIY solution is complicated by how firebase works. To search an arbitrary collection for a text match, you have to download the entire collection to the client. While with small amounts of data, I think doing client-side searching is certainly the most simple option. However, anything beyond a trivial collection size and the bandwidth/cpu constraints become non-trivial. In my experience, this point arrives much earlier than you'd think--i.e., it doesn't take a very large collection to become unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't support searching thru content like that (in any language SDK). From a [Google Groups Post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/MKW7k6Z0QDU) in July '16:

> As a company that understands search, we're also a company that
>   understands using the best tool for the job. For fuzzy matching and
>   contains, a NoSQL, realtime data store isn't the correct tool--these
>   queries would be slow and scale poorly.  BigQuery or ElasticSearch are
>   the right tool for providing useful results in a scalable and robust
>   manner.
>
> Right now, this involves deploying a small node script to sync your
>   search results with the realtime data, as explained in the article
>   with the sample Flashlight lib. In the future, it will become more
>   "effortless" as we add integrations between Firebase and Cloud
>   products, particularly Cloud Functions and BigQuery interoperability.

BigQuery is, as I understand it, not specifically designed for user-facing search.

Elasticsearch (specifically, the Firebase plugin `Flashlight`) is a potential solution, but as you alluded to, it's an incredible amount of overhead (deploying/managing or renting an ES cluster, configuring the plugin, etc.). If content search is an important enough part of your app to justify that time/$, you may want to consider solutions beyond Firebase for your database needs, as it's by far one of the service's weakest areas.

In my opinion, you have a few options beyond `Flashlight`:

1. Algolia, a Search-as-a-service provider, [does offer integration with Firebase](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/), but I've never used it & so can't offer much more than to say that it exists.
2. Another alternative might be maintaining a collection of documents you want to search on another service, like [AWS Cloud Search](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/)
3. Depending on the stage of your project & your needs, consider other Backends-as-a-Service that support more in terms of querying. E.g., GraphQL-as-a-service backends, like Scaphold.io, Graph.cool, and Reindex are all built on SQL databases, and (I believe) all support multiple types of querying.