# How can I make advanced queries in firebase?

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, web, querying

Well guys, I'm facing a problem with firebase. I'm trying to query a list of users in my database by their names using a searchbar. The problem is that in most of the acticles that I've seen about it on internet recommend to use ElasticSearch and Algolia (which is paid) instead of firebase query API to advanced queries, because the last one isn't enough to do this. They said that to get started with ElasticSearch I would have to upgrade my firebase from Spark to Blaze option (which is paid too), but I'm only a student in a small project and I don't have money for that. Is there another way to do advanced queries in my firebase project? Please, could you guys recommend a free solution to my problem? Thx!

Comment: If you are considering doing a live Firebase search as the user is typing... Don't. It will make your UI laggy and somewhat unresponsive - the internet just isn't fast enough to push data as fast as some users can type - and the larger the dataset that's returned, the laggier it will be. You will be better off with a search button or some other mechanic, or load the dataset once and filter in code (which is fast enough!). See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365157/wildcard-query-on-firebase/36366619#36366619) for one option to create your own wildcard search.

Answer (score 0):

Algolia has a free pan that could do the job (10K searchable records + 100K ops per month as of July 2017). I don't know the size of your project but it gets you started.

I don't see any limitation on the Firebase pricing page about integration with external services. Also, this is $25/months.

If you don't want (can't go) with Algolia, you can setup an elastic search capable cluster pretty easily on a cheap server (Linode or Digital Ocean for $5-$10 /month).