# Advanced search with Firebase on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, database, nosql

After reading the Firebase documentation, I understood that the logical structure in NoSql is totally different than in SQlite. I can do basic searches ordered with:

`orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()` and `orderByValue()` and filtered with 
`startAt()`, `endAt()` and `equalTo()`.

I'm building an app similar to the Bible. The app project requires that there be search filters, such as:

- "Starting with": ex: **Exce**lent
- "Containing": ex: Ex**che**nt
- "All Words": ex: **Jesus** is the **same**
- Exact Phrase: ex: **Jesus is the same**

The Firebase Realtime Database function is excellent for fixing typing errors or missing text, once the broadcast changes on all devices, this is undoubtedly something phenomenal.

Considering the image:

[See the structure of JSON in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DkDu.jpg)

1. Is it possible to do these search filters with Firebase?
2. What is the best way to build these filters using Firebase's own API?
3. Would I have to use these same filters with the offline data?

Comment: It is not really possible. There are limited workarounds I think.

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have text searching as you describe.

Comment: Is there any other DataBase that when changing or adding data, it makes a broadcast, changing on all devices? What would be the best option?

Comment: Yes, you can perform these kinda of queries. However, you have to do them in a 'NoSQL'  way. You could 'push the easy button' with [ElasticSearch](https://medium.com/joolsoftware/extending-firebase-with-cloud-functions-elasticsearch-129fbbb951e0) or craft your own search engine. A lot of depends on much much text you have. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365157/wildcard-query-on-firebase/36366619#36366619) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538863/firebase-query-containing-value/38541967#38541967) for some hints. You can also filter in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a think as a `LIKE` query equivalent in Firebase. You could create an extra node like this:

```
"common_queries": {
    "jesus": {
     "0": "awdawdn",
     "1": "oiefpowmfpowmf"
    },
    "eggcelent":{
     "0": "oiefpowmfpowmf"
    }
}
```

Then you can query trying to hit a key, and the results are the reference to the keys of other nodes.

There is another alternative wich involves using the `startAt()` method and `endAt()`, by adding the last text searchable value, here is a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=4) for it

I think Firebase is a tool in your toolbelt, in this case, is not the most suitable tool. Don't drill a hole with a circular saw, just use a drill.

Comment: Using your tip, it worked. I was able to do a Query by bringing all paragraphs of a book and using Array to do the word search. Thank you!

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro Great! Wich tip, the video or the "common_queries" node?

Comment: paragrafos ----> UHIudiuhiUHRI10 ----> texto: "valor" banco de dados = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance (); reference = database.getReference ("paragrafos"); Consulta de consulta = reference.orderByChild ("id"). EqualTo (msgId);

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Unfortunately, `Firebase` does not provide a text search mechanism as you described in your post and as far as i know, there is no other database which provides something like this by default.